# Gnosis-Safe: Batching Uniswap transactions using Transaction-Builder Not Working

Tags: uniswap, gnosis-safe

I'm trying to create a tx batch by pasting in a json formatted snippet(below) into Transaction-Builder:

```
{
  "IVSwapRouter.ExactInputSingleParams": {
"tokenIn": "0xa1bB1cF6B9A5B77c8a670925601378Cb57B7C824",
"tokenOut": "0x59c57F9bf023B6703944CBC3e605bbbaa254167B",
"fee": 500,
"recipient": "0xa276bCa4....723a7",
"amountIn": 20000000000000000000,
"amountOutMin": 0,
"sqrtPriceLimitX96": 0
}
}
```

I've tried many variations, including adding the array and up loading json files, nothing worked.

[image: Just one of many errors I've received]

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Here is the big picture as it may be helpful:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I hope someone finds this answer helpful, I'm sorry but I was unable to get the "exactInputSingle" function to work using the specified formats. Unfortunately, the Gnosis chat support person was unable to answer my question and directed me here. Hopefully someday someone from the Gnosis Tech Team can provide an answer.

Below is the work around I found, albeit using the Uniswap V2 version and not the V3:

After loading the SwapRouter2 Contract (0x68b3465833fb72A70ecDF485E0e4C7bD8665Fc45) select "SwapExactTokensForTokens" from the "Contract Method Selector" field and use that function instead.  In doing so the inputs are broken down into fields rather than requiring a json formatted input.

You'll need to enter the data manually, which will include using BigNumbers uint256 for amountIn and a path array for the ordered list of tokens to swap through, which in my case was just one token ([0xabc...4cc]).

Here is the link to the IV2SwapRouter functions: https://github.com/Uniswap/swap-router-contracts/blob/main/contracts/interfaces/IV2SwapRouter.sol

[image]